# How to stop UWP app close or termination on sleep or device lock?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I have developed a UWP app, that is required to run long hours ... The target devices are surface go and pro and all Windows10 laptops.  the app is suddenly terminated after lock or standby for some time on the surface go.  I want the app display in the same sate even after unlocking the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UWP apps will suspend when they are in a non-use state such as in the background (or lock screen) for reasons of power-saving and system usage.

But for some applications that need to run continuously in the background, UWP provides extended execution to delay application suspension:

- [Postpone app suspension with extended execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution)

---

If your application is not going to be submitted to the Microsoft Store, then after Windows 10 1703, a restricted capability is provided: `extendedExecutionUnconstrained`.

After this capability is turned on, the application can continue to run when it is minimized.

```xml
<Package
    ...
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
  ...
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="extendedExecutionUnconstrained"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

- [Run in the background indefinitely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly#run-while-minimized)